# Fragment transitions defined in xml do not work

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-transitions

I have added fragment transitions to values-21/styles.xml as follows:

```
    <item name="android:fragmentEnterTransition">@transition/window_enter</item>
    <item name="android:fragmentExitTransition">@transition/window_exit</item>
    <item name="android:fragmentReturnTransition">@transition/window_return</item>
    <item name="android:fragmentReenterTransition">@transition/window_reenter</item>
```

**transition/window_enter.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<slide />
```

**transition/window_exit**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<slide/>
```

**transition/window_return**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<explode/>
```

**transition/window_reenter**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<explode/>
```

I am adding the fragments with a normal fragment transaction. I apply no calls to transition API in the fragment code like `fragment.setEnterTransition()` as I expect transitions to be applied automatically given the transitions defined in styles.xml. I have no idea what is wrong. [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment) does not say much with fragment transitions.

Comment: why values-21/styles.xml, why not values/styles.xml?

Comment: @MadLeo because the transitions API is supported in API 21+.

Comment: Maybe it is because you use support fragments?

Comment: Is there something wrong with using support fragments @Ufkoku?

Comment: @codezombie Maybe they are not using transition attrs in android: name space

Answer (score 1):

I believe, you have not given the duration value. Below is a sample slide transition

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <transitionSet
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <Slide android:duration="10000">
        <targets>
            <target android:targetId="@+id/timer_clockView" />
            <target android:targetId="@+id/ic_wifi" />
            <target android:targetId="@+id/ic_lock" />
            <target android:targetId="@+id/ic_volume" />
        </targets>
     </Slide>
</transitionSet>
```

**Note:** Make sure you are using android.support.v4.app.Fragment and not android.app.Fragment, latter will be depreciated by Android in the near future.

Comment: No. Adding duration has no effect.

Comment: @codezombie are you using support libraries and your API version?

Comment: Yes @Harish. Support libraries. In fact from the androidx package. Minimum API level set to 21.

Comment: @codezombie go to your fragments onResume() method and then use getEnterTransition() and debug whether it is a non null value... If that's the case then you are not properly setting the transitions which by your code snippet looks fine. 

If it's non null value and it's not animating, then it's a miss match of Fragment related libraries..